# Java stream filter specified variable, delete it and delete next 3 variables in row

Tags: java, java-stream

Is it possible to find in stream specified variable and delete the next 3 iterated objects?

```
List<Double> hoursList = Arrays.asList(8.00,8.15,8.30, 8.45, 9.00,9.15, 9.30, 9.45,10.00,
            10.15,10.30,10.45,11.00);

Double visitTime = hoursList.get(4);
int n = 3;

List<Double> hours = hoursList.stream().filter(x -> !x.equals(visitTime)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

this code just delete 1 object 9.00 from List it's possible to delete the next 3 objects in the row?

Expected output:

```
[8.00,8.15,8.30, 8.45,10.00,10.15,10.30,10.45,11.00]
```

Comment: If you want to delete items from the `List`, make sure you instantiate it as `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList())` instead of `Arrays.asList()`. `Arrays.asList()` returns a fixed size wrapper around an array and is directly backed by the array. Otherwise you will get an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Do you want to remove all the *9 o'clocks*?

Comment: here is my primary problem why I can't edit my list by index in loops by .add and .remove. Thanks a lot i spend half day to try solve this. 'List<Double> hoursList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(8.00, 8.15, 8.30, 8.45, 9.00, 9.15, 9.30, 9.45, 10.00, 10.15, 10.30, 10.45, 11.00)); ' but now i learn something about streams and its look better than loops. Thanks @Oboe

Comment: Are you using `double` values for times? By all means don’t. Use `LocalTime` objects.

Comment: yes i'm  using double values. I just started make my own web app and all hints ale usefull. will try use LocalTime objects @Ole V.V.

Comment: Dawid Dawid, glad it helped. I updated my answer and included this comment so you can accept the the answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use concatenation of two streams. Using `takeWhile`, `dropWhile` and `skip`, then concat two streams together, will return desired result:

```
    List<Double> hours = Stream.concat(
            hoursList.stream()
                    .takeWhile(e -> !e.equals(visitTime)),
            hoursList.stream()
                    .dropWhile(e -> !e.equals(visitTime))
                    .skip(3)
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: why not simply `hoursList.stream().takeWhile(e -> !e.equals(visitTime)).skip(N+1).collect(Collectors.toList())`?

Comment: @Naman it stops in 9.00 and delete first 4 indexes. summary 'hours' is empty.

Comment: As long as incorrecly using `double` numbers for times adding 0.15 won’t help for removing 9.45 and 10.00 (9.45 + 0.15 equals 9.6 — approximately; don’t expect double math to be exact).

Comment: solution @miljon work great for me. its what i am looking for. i hope it help other people to solve their problems

Comment: @OleV.V.oh god you are right I was thinking about time and forgot they are numbers xd

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment in the original question, if you want to delete items from the `List`, make sure you instantiate it as `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList())` or `new ArrayList<>(List.of())` instead of `Arrays.asList()`. `Arrays.asList()` returns a fixed size wrapper around an `array` and is directly backed by the `array`. Otherwise you will get an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Having said that, I would use `subList` for that job, it is much more simple:

```
hoursList.subList(4, 4 + 3 + 1).clear();
```

If you prefer a method that accepts parameters for more flexibility (and checks for potential index out of bounds):

```
public List<Double> removeHours(List<Double> hours, double hour, int nextHours) {

    int startIndex = hours.indexOf(hour);

    int finalIndex = Math.min(startIndex + nextHours + 1, hours.size());

    hours.subList(startIndex, finalIndex).clear();

    return hours;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
List<Double> hoursRemoved = removeHours(hoursList, 9.0, 3);   
System.out.println(hoursRemoved);
```

**Output**

```
[8.0, 8.15, 8.3, 8.45, 10.0, 10.15, 10.3, 10.45, 11.0]
```

Comment: since `index` is already a part of the input in the question, you could have used that in the method signature directly.

Comment: I’m just guessing that the real input is the hour and he wants to block a timeslot.

Comment: If that assumption holds, then the OP is better relying on the [answer by Harshal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63095057/1746118) and that's what we've been discussing in comments too. Voted the question to actually need clarity in that case.

Comment: I agree, the OP has options to choose the one that fits better his underlining goal. But the other option is valid only if the time slots are all equal size.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are times, handle them as times, not as double numbers. The `LocaTime` class of java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is what you need.

```
    List<LocalTime> hoursList = Stream.iterate(LocalTime.of(8, 0), t -> t.plusMinutes(15))
            .limit(13)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(hoursList);
    
    LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.of(8, 45);
    LocalTime endTime = startTime.plusHours(1);
    List<LocalTime> hours = new ArrayList<>(hoursList);
    hours.removeIf(t -> ! t.isBefore(startTime) && t.isBefore(endTime));

    System.out.println(hours);
```

Output:

> ```
> [08:00, 08:15, 08:30, 08:45, 09:00, 09:15, 09:30, 09:45, 10:00, 10:15, 10:30, 10:45, 11:00]
> [08:00, 08:15, 08:30, 09:45, 10:00, 10:15, 10:30, 10:45, 11:00]
> ```

I agree with Harshal Parekh that it’s more readable and simpler to use `removeIf()` than a stream operation. Both options are possible. For `removeIf()` to work we need to make sure that we have got a modifiable list. Copying into a new `ArrayList` ensures this.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.